# Problem in shutting down elementaryos

Tags: dual-boot, laptop, shutdown

I can't shutdown my laptop running elementaryOS Hera 5.1.4. Whenever I try to shut it down the screen goes off,there is no sound but the power-indicator stays on until I switch it off using the power button.
I tried using 'sudo shutdown -h now' but the problem persists.
Also when I shut down from windows(dual-boot), it shuts down normally.
 I am using Acer A315-42 with AMD Ryzen 3200U.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with Dell Inspiron Ryzen 3 2300u. :(
what a suckO update!!

Comment: I am having the same problem with my desktop too. It happens after latest update. It is really wired.